# Geting html content properly when the script is runned for individual IDs, but when trying on loop, after few iterations, getting error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

columns=['ID','Toll Plaza Name','State','Type Of Vehicle','Single Journey','Return Journey','Monthly Pass','Commercial Vehicle Registered within the district of plaza']
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
row_count=0


URL = "https://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation.aspx?TollPlazaID="


for i in range(0,491):

    URL+=str(i+4)
    print(i+4)
    r = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'DivContaint','class':'content'})
    #print(div)
    name= div.find('lable').text
    #print('Name: ',name)
    state=div.find('div', attrs = {'class':'PA15'}).p.text.split('in')[1].split('Stretch')[0].strip()
    #print('State: ', state)
    table=div.find('table',attrs={'class':'tollinfotbl'})
    rows=table.find_all('tr')
    for j in range(1,14,2):
        df.loc[row_count,'ID']=i+4
        df.loc[row_count,'Toll Plaza Name']=name
        df.loc[row_count,'State']=state
        typeOfVehicle=rows[j].th.text
        df.loc[row_count,'Type Of Vehicle']=typeOfVehicle.strip()
        td=rows[j].find_all('td')
        df.loc[row_count,'Single Journey']=td[0].text
        df.loc[row_count,'Return Journey']=td[1].text
        df.loc[row_count,'Monthly Pass']=td[2].text
        df.loc[row_count,'Commercial Vehicle Registered within the district of plaza']=td[3].text

        row_count+=1
    del r, soup, div, name, state, table, td    
    df.to_excel("output.xlsx")  
    #time.sleep(2)
```

### Output:
4
5
6
7
8

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
15     div = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'DivContaint','class':'content'})
16     #print(div)
---> 17     name= div.find('lable').text
18     #print('Name: ',name)
19     state=div.find('div', attrs = {'class':'PA15'}).p.text.split('in')[1].split('Stretch')[0].strip()

### AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

So, on the 8th id iteration, i am getting empty div content. But if i try just for that particular id i.e. 8. getting proper output.

Comment: This basically means that the element *you think* is in the source is actually not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the way you have the logic, it's not iterating through each "plaza", but concatenating it. By that "8th" plaza, it's trying to go to url `'https://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation.aspx?TollPlazaID=45678'` which doesn't exist.

Also, if you are just adding 4 to each i, why not just adjust the range from `(0,491)` to `(4,495)`?

I'd also consider using pandas to parse that table. Just a personnel preference.

Lastly, yo do realize after each iteration, you are overwriting your `output.xlsx` file? I suppose it's fine as you are just appending to it, but not sure that's what you want.

Here's the code with a sample of first pages 4-15 (I'm not going to sit through all 490+ iterations).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

root_url = "https://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation.aspx?TollPlazaID="

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(4,495):
    url = f'{root_url}{i}'
    print(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    
    df = pd.read_html(r.text)[0].dropna(how='all', axis=0)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'DivContaint','class':'content'})
    #print(div)
    name= div.find('lable').text
    #print('Name: ',name)
    state=div.find('div', attrs = {'class':'PA15'}).p.text.split('in')[1].split('Stretch')[0].strip()
    #print('State: ', state)
    
    df['ID'] = i
    df['Toll Plaza Name'] = name
    df['State'] = state
    
    final_df = final_df.append(df).reset_index(drop=True)

    #time.sleep(2)
    
final_df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(final_df.to_string())
        Type of vehicle  Single Journey  Return Journey  Monthly Pass  Commercial Vehicle Registered within the district of plaza  ID                                   Toll Plaza Name                                         State
0          Car/Jeep/Van            95.0           145.0        2860.0                                                         NaN   4   Thakurtola (End of Durg Bypass) ( BOT (Toll) )                                   Chhattisgarh
1                   LCV           165.0           250.0        5005.0                                                         NaN   4   Thakurtola (End of Durg Bypass) ( BOT (Toll) )                                   Chhattisgarh
2             Bus/Truck           335.0           500.0       10010.0                                                         NaN   4   Thakurtola (End of Durg Bypass) ( BOT (Toll) )                                   Chhattisgarh
3   Upto 3 Axle Vehicle           535.0           805.0       16090.0                                                         NaN   4   Thakurtola (End of Durg Bypass) ( BOT (Toll) )                                   Chhattisgarh
4           4 to 6 Axle           535.0           805.0       16090.0                                                         NaN   4   Thakurtola (End of Durg Bypass) ( BOT (Toll) )                                   Chhattisgarh
5               HCM/EME           535.0           805.0       16090.0                                                         NaN   4   Thakurtola (End of Durg Bypass) ( BOT (Toll) )                                   Chhattisgarh
6        7 or more Axle           535.0           805.0       16090.0                                                         NaN   4   Thakurtola (End of Durg Bypass) ( BOT (Toll) )                                   Chhattisgarh
7          Car/Jeep/Van            55.0            80.0        1795.0                                                        25.0   5                       Bankapur ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
8                   LCV            85.0           130.0        2905.0                                                        45.0   5                       Bankapur ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
9             Bus/Truck           180.0           275.0        6080.0                                                        90.0   5                       Bankapur ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
10  Upto 3 Axle Vehicle           200.0           300.0        6635.0                                                       100.0   5                       Bankapur ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
11          4 to 6 Axle           285.0           430.0        9540.0                                                       145.0   5                       Bankapur ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
12              HCM/EME           285.0           430.0        9540.0                                                       145.0   5                       Bankapur ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
13       7 or more Axle           350.0           525.0       11610.0                                                       175.0   5                       Bankapur ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
14         Car/Jeep/Van           100.0           145.0        3270.0                                                         NaN   6                      Hirebagewadi ( BOT (Toll) )                                      Karnataka
15                  LCV           160.0           240.0        5280.0                                                         NaN   6                      Hirebagewadi ( BOT (Toll) )                                      Karnataka
16            Bus/Truck           330.0           500.0       11065.0                                                         NaN   6                      Hirebagewadi ( BOT (Toll) )                                      Karnataka
17  Upto 3 Axle Vehicle           520.0           780.0       17350.0                                                         NaN   6                      Hirebagewadi ( BOT (Toll) )                                      Karnataka
18          4 to 6 Axle           520.0           780.0       17350.0                                                         NaN   6                      Hirebagewadi ( BOT (Toll) )                                      Karnataka
19              HCM/EME           520.0           780.0       17350.0                                                         NaN   6                      Hirebagewadi ( BOT (Toll) )                                      Karnataka
20       7 or more Axle           635.0           950.0       21120.0                                                         NaN   6                      Hirebagewadi ( BOT (Toll) )                                      Karnataka
21         Car/Jeep/Van            60.0             NaN           NaN                                                         NaN   7          Durg Bypass (Dhamdanaka) ( BOT (Toll) )                                   Chhattisgarh
22                  LCV           125.0             NaN           NaN                                                         NaN   7          Durg Bypass (Dhamdanaka) ( BOT (Toll) )                                   Chhattisgarh
23            Bus/Truck           185.0             NaN           NaN                                                         NaN   7          Durg Bypass (Dhamdanaka) ( BOT (Toll) )                                   Chhattisgarh
24  Upto 3 Axle Vehicle           280.0             NaN           NaN                                                         NaN   7          Durg Bypass (Dhamdanaka) ( BOT (Toll) )                                   Chhattisgarh
25          4 to 6 Axle           280.0             NaN           NaN                                                         NaN   7          Durg Bypass (Dhamdanaka) ( BOT (Toll) )                                   Chhattisgarh
26              HCM/EME           375.0             NaN           NaN                                                         NaN   7          Durg Bypass (Dhamdanaka) ( BOT (Toll) )                                   Chhattisgarh
27       7 or more Axle           280.0             NaN           NaN                                                         NaN   7          Durg Bypass (Dhamdanaka) ( BOT (Toll) )                                   Chhattisgarh
28         Car/Jeep/Van            30.0            45.0         980.0                                                        15.0   8                       Hattargi ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
29                  LCV            45.0            70.0        1580.0                                                        25.0   8                       Hattargi ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
30            Bus/Truck           100.0           150.0        3310.0                                                        50.0   8                       Hattargi ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
31  Upto 3 Axle Vehicle           110.0           160.0        3610.0                                                        55.0   8                       Hattargi ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
32          4 to 6 Axle           155.0           235.0        5190.0                                                        80.0   8                       Hattargi ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
33              HCM/EME           155.0           235.0        5190.0                                                        80.0   8                       Hattargi ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
34       7 or more Axle           190.0           285.0        6315.0                                                        95.0   8                       Hattargi ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
35         Car/Jeep/Van            75.0           115.0        2500.0                                                        40.0   9                        Kognoli ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
36                  LCV           120.0           180.0        4040.0                                                        60.0   9                        Kognoli ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
37            Bus/Truck           255.0           380.0        8465.0                                                       125.0   9                        Kognoli ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
38  Upto 3 Axle Vehicle           275.0           415.0        9235.0                                                       140.0   9                        Kognoli ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
39          4 to 6 Axle           400.0           595.0       13275.0                                                       200.0   9                        Kognoli ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
40              HCM/EME           400.0           595.0       13275.0                                                       200.0   9                        Kognoli ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
41       7 or more Axle           485.0           725.0       16165.0                                                       240.0   9                        Kognoli ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
42         Car/Jeep/Van            90.0           135.0        3015.0                                                        45.0  10                            Tundla ( BOT (Toll) )                                  Uttar Pradesh
43                  LCV           145.0           220.0        4870.0                                                        75.0  10                            Tundla ( BOT (Toll) )                                  Uttar Pradesh
44            Bus/Truck           305.0           460.0       10205.0                                                       155.0  10                            Tundla ( BOT (Toll) )                                  Uttar Pradesh
45  Upto 3 Axle Vehicle           335.0           500.0       11130.0                                                       165.0  10                            Tundla ( BOT (Toll) )                                  Uttar Pradesh
46          4 to 6 Axle           480.0           720.0       16000.0                                                       240.0  10                            Tundla ( BOT (Toll) )                                  Uttar Pradesh
47              HCM/EME           480.0           720.0       16000.0                                                       240.0  10                            Tundla ( BOT (Toll) )                                  Uttar Pradesh
48       7 or more Axle           585.0           870.0       19480.0                                                       290.0  10                            Tundla ( BOT (Toll) )                                  Uttar Pradesh
49         Car/Jeep/Van            25.0            40.0         895.0                                                        15.0  11                 Brahamarakotlu ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
50                  LCV            45.0            65.0        1445.0                                                        20.0  11                 Brahamarakotlu ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
51            Bus/Truck            90.0           135.0        3025.0                                                        45.0  11                 Brahamarakotlu ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
52  Upto 3 Axle Vehicle           100.0           150.0        3300.0                                                        50.0  11                 Brahamarakotlu ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
53          4 to 6 Axle           140.0           215.0        4745.0                                                        70.0  11                 Brahamarakotlu ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
54              HCM/EME           140.0           215.0        4745.0                                                        70.0  11                 Brahamarakotlu ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
55       7 or more Axle           175.0           260.0        5775.0                                                        85.0  11                 Brahamarakotlu ( Public Funded )                                      Karnataka
56         Car/Jeep/Van            25.0            35.0         785.0                                                        10.0  12      Cable Stayed Naini Bridge ( Public Funded )   i Bridge ( Public Funded )  Km 1.600 - NH-30
57                  LCV            40.0            55.0        1265.0                                                        20.0  12      Cable Stayed Naini Bridge ( Public Funded )   i Bridge ( Public Funded )  Km 1.600 - NH-30
58            Bus/Truck            80.0           120.0        2650.0                                                        40.0  12      Cable Stayed Naini Bridge ( Public Funded )   i Bridge ( Public Funded )  Km 1.600 - NH-30
59  Upto 3 Axle Vehicle            85.0           130.0        2890.0                                                        45.0  12      Cable Stayed Naini Bridge ( Public Funded )   i Bridge ( Public Funded )  Km 1.600 - NH-30
60          4 to 6 Axle           125.0           185.0        4155.0                                                        60.0  12      Cable Stayed Naini Bridge ( Public Funded )   i Bridge ( Public Funded )  Km 1.600 - NH-30
61              HCM/EME           125.0           185.0        4155.0                                                        60.0  12      Cable Stayed Naini Bridge ( Public Funded )   i Bridge ( Public Funded )  Km 1.600 - NH-30
62       7 or more Axle           150.0           230.0        5055.0                                                        75.0  12      Cable Stayed Naini Bridge ( Public Funded )   i Bridge ( Public Funded )  Km 1.600 - NH-30
63         Car/Jeep/Van            80.0           120.0        2655.0                                                        40.0  13                                    Bassi ( OMT )                                      Rajasthan
64                  LCV           130.0           195.0        4285.0                                                        65.0  13                                    Bassi ( OMT )                                      Rajasthan
65            Bus/Truck           270.0           405.0        8980.0                                                       135.0  13                                    Bassi ( OMT )                                      Rajasthan
66  Upto 3 Axle Vehicle           295.0           440.0        9795.0                                                       145.0  13                                    Bassi ( OMT )                                      Rajasthan
67          4 to 6 Axle           420.0           635.0       14080.0                                                       210.0  13                                    Bassi ( OMT )                                      Rajasthan
68              HCM/EME           420.0           635.0       14080.0                                                       210.0  13                                    Bassi ( OMT )                                      Rajasthan
69       7 or more Axle           515.0           770.0       17145.0                                                       255.0  13                                    Bassi ( OMT )                                      Rajasthan
70         Car/Jeep/Van            70.0           100.0        2260.0                                                        35.0  14                                    Aroli ( OMT )                                      Rajasthan
71                  LCV           110.0           165.0        3645.0                                                        55.0  14                                    Aroli ( OMT )                                      Rajasthan
72            Bus/Truck           230.0           345.0        7640.0                                                       115.0  14                                    Aroli ( OMT )                                      Rajasthan
73  Upto 3 Axle Vehicle           250.0           375.0        8335.0                                                       125.0  14                                    Aroli ( OMT )                                      Rajasthan
74          4 to 6 Axle           360.0           540.0       11985.0                                                       180.0  14                                    Aroli ( OMT )                                      Rajasthan
75              HCM/EME           360.0           540.0       11985.0                                                       180.0  14                                    Aroli ( OMT )                                      Rajasthan
76       7 or more Axle           440.0           655.0       14590.0                                                       220.0  14                                    Aroli ( OMT )                                      Rajasthan
```